# php running out of memory while constructing large array from database

Tags: php, arrays, csv, out-of-memory, php-curl

I have a project were i need to pull up to 50,000 records from a database and create a csv file with that data. My problem is that the server will only return 300 records at a time. How can i effectively run this script apx 166 times while storing each response from the server in an array without running out of memory?

Once the last call request the server has been made, i will run the function (not shown) to create the CSV from the array.

class RetrieveData {

```
public $fields = array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4");// List of names to pull from database

public $batchSize; //max 300 records returned at a time 
public $NextPage;
public $nextPageToken; //token returned from previous call for paging


public function getData(){

    $url = $this->host . "/rest/v1/list/" . $this->listId . "/leads.json?access_token=" . $this->getToken();
    if (isset($this->fields)){
        $url = $url . "&fields=" . $this::csvString($this->fields);
    }
    if (isset($this->batchSize)){
        $url = $url . "&batchSize=" . $this->batchSize;
    }
    if (isset($this->nextPageToken)){
        $url = $url . "&nextPageToken=" . $this->nextPageToken;
    }

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('accept: application/json',));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return $response;
}

private function getToken(){
    $ch = curl_init($this->host . "/identity/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" . $this->clientId . "&client_secret=" . $this->clientSecret);
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('accept: application/json',));
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    $token = $response->access_token;
    return $token;
}

    private static function csvString($fields){

    $csvString = "";

    $rr= implode(",",$fields);

    $FF = str_replace(' ', '', $rr);

    $csvString = $FF;

    $csvString = rtrim($csvString,',');
    }

    return $csvString;
}
```

}

Comment: Why not create the CSV in place, so you're not using up as much memory? Otherwise, you'll need to raise your memory limit.

Comment: What do you mean? create the CSV in place..

Comment: Instead of creating the array and then passing the large array to a function to create the csv, create the CSV within the loop. By the way, there are functions to [create a CSV string](https://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) instead of implementing one yourself

Comment: That makes sense. let me explore this. And thanks for your quick response!

Comment: Just circling back on this. You suggestion worked great thank you! This should be an answer!